# select and get the most repeated occurrence on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a table and i need to recover most repeated occurrence 
in the example the occurrence repeats is **kills:8**
I not want to get the most value, i need get the most repeated value

```
id | member | kills 
1  | -      | 9 
2  | -      | 8 
3  | -      | 4 
4  | -      | 8 
5  | -      | 7
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by kills, then order by count of the values in a descending manner, then limit to only one row.

```
SELECT
    kills,
    COUNT(id) AS kill_count
FROM table
GROUP BY kills
ORDER BY kill_count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT kills, COUNT(id) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY kills HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

Comment: it only returned 1 id

Answer (score 1):

[Juz refer the link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34e028/7/0)

```
SELECT kills,
       count(kills)
FROM TEMP
GROUP BY kills
ORDER BY count(kills) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

My only idea is to run a while loop that counts each value in the kills column, tallies it and then runs if statements to get the highest tally.  Hope this helps.